# Multiple NetworkStreams for each client

Tags: c#, networking, stream, networkstream

I have recently started getting into NetworkStreams, and I had a question.  I am currently creating a thread, and processing all incoming messages as they come in.

Here is the code to illustrate this:

```
client.Connect(serverEndPoint);
clientStream = client.GetStream();
client.NoDelay = true;

ctThread = new Thread(getMessage);
ctThread.Start();  

private void getMessage()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Byte[] data = new Byte[800];
        String responseData = String.Empty;
        Int32 bytes = clientStream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
        responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);

        MessageReceived(this, new ClientMessageEventArgs(responseData));
    }
}
```

In the above, I raise an event "MessageReceived" which is handled according the the packet data.  This works great, but also have a seperate case where I need to retrieve data immediately after I send my request.

Is it ok to have two streams per client?  Is this even possible to do on the same port?  How should this be handled?  Essentially, I want to be able to Send and then Receive data immediately after (blocking way).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read and write from network streams independently and in a thread safe manner. i.e. reading from one thread and writing from another.

If you checkout the open source network communication library [networkComms.net](https://bitbucket.org/MarcF/networkcomms.net) you can see how this is achieved independently in the sending method SendPacket() ([line 1304](https://bitbucket.org/MarcF/networkcomms.net/src/e29ed6459a3a/NetworkCommsDotNet/Connection.cs#cl-1304)) and receiving method IncomingPacketHandler() ([line 802](https://bitbucket.org/MarcF/networkcomms.net/src/e29ed6459a3a/NetworkCommsDotNet/Connection.cs#cl-802)).

Mx

Comment: I have been trying to avoid using a library for my communication, but I think I might just use this one.  Thanks.